# Error: Could not find a suitable provider for cron

Tags: puppet

From what I'm reading it seems cron is [built into Puppet](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/cron.html).

```
cron { 'apply puppet master config':
  command => 'puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/master.pp',
  hour    => [ 12, 0 ],
}
```

Yet when I try to run the above configuration I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find a suitable provider for cron

Why isn't Puppet using the built in cron type?

Comment: Does the binary `crontab` exist in your path? Which OS are you using, how did you install it? Do you have a cron package/daemon set up?

Comment: @DominicCleal I'm not sure how to check if `crontab` is in my path. I'm running inside a docker container with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `which crontab`, or `find /bin /usr/bin -name crontab`

Comment: "Why isn't Puppet using the built in cron type?" You mean provider, and it could not be found, which heavily implies cron is not installed/available on the system you are managing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that my system had cron jobs located in `/etc/cron.daily` 
and `/etc/cron.weekly` the cron package on ubuntu which Puppet relies on wasn't installed. *(As pointed out in comments by Dominic & Matt).*

I was able to fix this by adding this to my configuration file before running the cron configuration:

```
package { 'cron':
  ensure => installed,
}
```